# Check if Range of Cells Contains Specific Texts

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I was working on a formula that would be placed in the "%" column that checks if any of the values within the Cat, Dog and Mouse columns that contain all "Yes" and if so, to have "90" stated. If there is a "No" however, to have "70" stated in the % column. I have had success so far with the formula for the columns that all contain "Yes" using:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(F8:L8,"Yes"),"90%","75%")
```

[image]

However, when I copy the formula down the % column, it doesn't work for the column for row 4, it leaves it at 90 instead of 70. As shown in the image below:

[image]

Your feedback is greatly appreciated thanks!

Comment: Needs to be like this `=IF(COUNTIF(B2:D2,"Yes")=3,0.9,0.7)`

Comment: Replace your `COUNTIF(...)` with `COUNTIF(F8:L8,"Yes")=COLUMNS(F8:L8)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following formula:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>A2</kbd>

```
=IF(COUNTIF(B2:D2,"Yes")=3,0.9,0.7)
```

---

Or, can use <kbd>COLUMNS()</kbd> function for the total number of column counts to match with the total number of `Yes` that said the formula will be

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>A2</kbd>

```
=IF(COUNTIF(B2:D2,"Yes")=COLUMNS(B2:D2),0.9,0.7)
```

---

Your present formula is not working because it does checks how many `Yes`s are there, but does not validates whether the number is equal to number of columns where the yes are present, i.e. since you have three columns it needs to validate, whether it is available across the three columns.

```
=IF(COUNTIF(F8:L8,"Yes"),"90%","75%")
```

---

So your present formula returns, for the first 3 rows, as 3 and since its a number hence the <kbd>IF()</kbd> works only with `TRUE` argument and returns always as `Yes` irrespective of the number counts, so to make it work, you need to follow the formula as i have given on above.

---